# Re-running repeatable migrations with flyway without checksum changes

Tags: postgresql, migration, flyway

So I have a couple of repeatable migrations.

1. `R__first.sql` creates one view (drops it & cascades before creating).
2. `R__second.sql` creates another view that references the first one.

Now let's say I modify the first migration and the resulting view no longer includes a column that is used by the second one. Flyway will happily re-run this first migration, the first view will be recreated, and the second view will be dropped because of the cascade option.

What I would want to happen after that, is that the second (dependent) migration would be run as well, and would throw an error (because it uses a column that's no longer there).

Is something like that possible?

To somehow force flyway to check if the result of an existing migration is no longer there?
Or is there maybe something like dependent migrations? That if one changes, others can be marked to be re-run despite having the same checksum.
Or maybe it's possible to hack something using afterMigrate? But without explicitly copy-pasting the same create-if-not-exists sql.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, and of course, just after posting this, I discovered that instead of dropping and then creating, you can just use `CREATE OR REPLACE`. This actually throws an error if you're trying to drop columns that are being used in another view.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but if you think you might drop columns, it's probably not a good candidate for a repeatable migration.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/database-migration-flyway-large-project/) describes the idea which might interest You.

In `R__second.sql` You can put the DDL into PLSQL, where You would first check what columns exist in view created in `R__first.sql` and conditionally recreate the second view.

In my project I have few views with `SELECT a.* FROM` and I am going this way.